# Using Pandas to read CSV containing some missing values

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I use Python 2.7 with Anaconda. I have a .csv file:

```
  action_type                action_detail secs_elapsed
0        data             similar_listings        255.0
1        data             similar_listings        183.0
2       click  change_trip_characteristics     175570.0
3         NaN                          NaN         86.0
4        data      wishlist_content_update       1535.0
```

The file contains some missing values and data types of each column are not necessarily similar. I used Pandas to load this .csv

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('the_file_name.csv', chunksize=1000, 
                         dtype={'action_type': str, 'action_detail': str,
                                'secs_elapsed': str})
```

For each chunk, I found that data type of some rows are not my instructions in function pd.read_csv. Let me show an example

```
chunk.ix[3, 'action_type']
Out[1]: nan
type(chunk.ix[3, 'action_type'])
Out[2]: float
```

My questions are

1. I want all datas type like my instruction, how could I do that?
2. I also want to replace these missing values, I have used `pandas.filna()` but it doesn't effect. I think it's due to data type. Could you please give nay hints for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `converters` instead of `dtype`:

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv('the_file_name.csv', chunksize=1000, delim_whitespace=True,
    converters={'action_type': str, 'action_detail': str,'secs_elapsed': str}):

>>> type(chunk.ix[3, 'action_type'])
str
```

Also, for your file example you need  to set `delim_whitespace=True`. Unless the real file is comma separated.